# How can i fix this error ? Resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-layout, manifest, intentfilter

I'm trying to run my new app on my phone but I'm facing this error:

> Android resource linking failed C:\Users\HP PAVILION G6-
>   1310\Miok\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:20:
>   error: unexpected element  found in
>   .

I have found  answers in stackoverflow but none of them worked for me.
Here are all my files:

**app:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.miwok"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

}
```

**main\AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.miwok">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name=".NumbersActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_numbers"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FamilyActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_family"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ColorsActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_colors"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PhrasesActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_phrases"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**debug\AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.miwok"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="29" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.miwok.NumbersActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_numbers"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" >

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.miwok.FamilyActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_family"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" >

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.miwok.ColorsActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_colors"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" >

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.miwok.PhrasesActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_phrases"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" >

            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void OpenNumbersList(View view)
    {
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_numbers"
        android:text="@string/category_numbers" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/family"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_family"
        android:text="@string/category_family" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colors"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        android:text="@string/category_colors" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phrases"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_phrases"
        android:text="@string/category_phrases" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably copied and pasted all codes from the git repository "https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/tree/Starter-code".Instead of copy and paste, write inside the string values(for example, "@ string / category numbers") in the AndroidManifest.xml file.You are seeing this error because Android studio does not recognise it.
Make sure the strings.xml file in the res folder is complete.